# Could not find Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components in VS2017

Tags: c#, c++

I successfully used VS 2015 (including c++ / c#) in the past and downloaded now the new VS 2017. Building the project, I got several warnings such as:

> (1) Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       The referenced component 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components'
>   could not be found.
>
> (2) Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the
>   assembly "Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components, Version=15.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
>   disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.
>
> (3) Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Warning       Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the
>   assembly "Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.UnitTesting,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a,
>   processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on
>   disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.

I tried now several options. Actually, the solution explorer shows under references the "Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components". I then changed the .NET target framework from 4.6.1 to 4.5.1 and the reference path to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SqlDb\` without no progress.

Maybe, some could help .. many thanks.

Comment: "Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components" can be seen in the solution explorer under reference only, but not in the object browser.

Comment: I too am having this issue. One of the "fixes" was to reinstall VS 2017. Did it. Didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would resolve this problem or if Sepp ever found a solution, but this problem sounds similar to one I had upgrading to 2017 on other projects. Adding updated MS Libraries via NuGet has worked for me.

Open **NuGet Package Manager** and search for **Microsoft.Data.Tools** to find Microsoft content similar to Microsoft.Data.Tools.Components.
There are two similar entries **Microsoft.Data.Tools.UnitTest** and **Microsoft.Data.Tools.MsBuild**

Try adding maybe the Microsoft.Data.Tools.MsBuild or both to your solution and recompile.  These libraries sound like they are the same base, and may include the 'Component' content also.  A Google found the same issue (i.e. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/09f82922-2fe5-46cc-bc70-b63f137aec28/visual-studio-2017-warning-issues-?forum=vssetup, and the Microsoft.Data.Tools.MsBuild package includes content similar to that mentioned both above and there. The MsBuild states: "You can use SSDT Transact-SQL design capabilities to build, debug, maintain, and refactor databases." - so I'm thinking this may be an update to your older set. If it doesn't work, just unselect them to uninstall.